# How to get a UNIQUE INDEX of 2 COLUMNS in both ways?

Tags: mysql

Here's a table called `friendship`:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| invited_by | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| recipient  | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table function is to store friendships between all the users. It can't be two lines with the same friendship as following:

```
+------------+-----------+
| invited_by | recipient |
+------------+-----------+
| someUser1  | someUser2 |
| someUser2  | someUser1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

How to avoid that case?

Comment: There's no built-in constraint like this. Either check for the other direction before inserting, or use a trigger to raise an error.

Comment: Before you execute the query to insert a friendship between two users check if one of them has sent an invite to another.
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (invited_by  = 'someUser1'  && recipient = 'someUser2') OR (invited_by = 'someUser2'  && recipient = 'someUser1')`

Comment: I thought there was a more economical way but I'll do this instead. Thanks guys!